# 'Cannot read property of undefined' error Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

So I have 2 views.
The first one shows a list of hotels.
The second one shows detailed info about the currently opened hotel from the list.

Hotels list component:

```
<li *ngFor="let hotel of hotels">
  <app-hotels-item [item]="hotel" routerLink="single-hotel/{{hotel.fields.slug}}"></app-hotels-item>
</li>
```

Single hotel component:

```
export class SingleHotelComponent implements OnInit {
  hotels: Entry<any>[] = [];
  slug: string;
  singleHotel: any;

  constructor(private contentfulService: ContentfulService, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.slug = route.snapshot.params.slug;

    this.contentfulService.getHotels()
      .then(hotels => this.hotels = hotels)
      .then(() => this.compareSlug());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  compareSlug(){
    this.singleHotel = this.hotels.find(o => o.fields.slug === this.slug);
  }
```

My understanding is that after getHotels() method fetches the data, it will run compareSlug() next.

But I'm getting multiple errors from my template file, which look like that the template tries to show data which is not ready yet:

```
'core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined at SingleHotelComponent_Template (single-hotel.component.html:15)
```

Am I missing something, or should I go with another approach?

Comment: try to change this `{{hotel.fields.slug}}` to this `{{hotel?.fields?.slug}}`

Comment: @SuneelKumar , you probably meant adding '?' to the view file which throws the error - I did replace
<h1 class="single-hotel-heading">{{ singleHotel.fields.name }}</h1>
with
<h1 class="single-hotel-heading">{{ singleHotel?.fields?.name }}</h1>

It resulted in console not showing any errors, but the <h1> tag renders empty, because Angular ignores the value which is not ready at the moment the view requests for it.
So definitely not the solution I'm looking for.
I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: It's not necessary! do you get your value later accurately?? did you try to check the output at all?